# Unable to pull JSON data from stats.nba.com

Tags: r, json

I've been having some difficulty getting data from stats.nba.com. I've been able to pull info pretty easily in the past, so wanted to see if you guys noticed any issues in my code or if you're running into the same problems.

I'm using `rjson`.

```
library(rjson)

url <- "https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0041800406"
a <- fromJSON(file = url)
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0041800406'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  URL 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0041800406': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
```

I can, however, see the data in JSON format by following the request url. Anybody notice any mistakes I'm making?

Comment: The code works on my PC. Can you add your ```sessionInfo()``` to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a specific answer; think it was due to some issue with my firewall. Was able to get everything to work on a different network.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can read the json file into a list object.

```
library(jsonlite)

read_json("https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0041800406")
```